# JSP GETTER SETTER SHOWING RESULT NULL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to retrieve and show data from getters of my java class but unable to show the result. It is showing 0 and null in my jsp page. I am unable to figure out this problem. I have added first the servlet code then DAO code then jsp code.

```
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String input = request.getParameter("list");
            String txtField = request.getParameter("txtField");
            String op = request.getParameter("op");
            String bSearch = request.getParameter("bookingSearch");



            try{
                if(op.equals("1")){
                    Searching search1 = new Searching();
                    search1.setInputList(input);
                    search1.setTxtField(txtField);
                    SearchDAO searchDAO = new SearchDAO();
                    boolean searchDriver = searchDAO.searchDriver(search1);
                    if(searchDriver){
                        response.sendRedirect("driversearchresult.jsp");


                        //response.sendRedirect("SearchOutPut.jsp?op=" + search1.getPassingValue());
                    }
                    else {
                        out.println("<html>");
                        out.println("<head>");
                        out.println("<script>");
                        out.println("alert('Record Not Found!')");
                        out.println("</script>");
                        out.println("<META HTTP-EQUIV= Refresh CONTENT=0;URL=SearchDriver.jsp>");
                    }

                }


    package com.vechile.dao;

    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import com.vechile.model.DriverSearchResult;
    import com.vechile.model.Searching;
    import com.vechile.utils.DBConnection;

    public class SearchDAO {
        private String sql;
        private ResultSet rs, rs1;

        public boolean searchDriver(Searching searching) {
            try {

                sql = String.format("select * from adddriver where (%s) = '%s'",
                        searching.getInputList(), searching.getTxtField());

                rs = DBConnection.executeQuery(sql);

                if(rs.next()) {
                    DriverSearchResult searchResult = new DriverSearchResult();
                    Integer driverId = new Integer(rs.getInt(1));
                    String driverIdString = driverId.toString();
                    searchResult.setId(driverIdString);
                    searchResult.setName(rs.getString("dname"));
                    searchResult.setAddress(rs.getString("daddress"));
                    searchResult.setCity(rs.getString("dcity"));
                    searchResult.setContact(rs.getString("dcontact"));
                    searchResult.setCountry(rs.getString("dcountry"));

                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }



        public boolean searchBooking(Searching searching) {
            try {
                sql = String.format(
                        "select * from booking where booking_id = '%s'",
                        searching.getBookingSearch());

                rs1 = DBConnection.executeQuery(sql);
                if (rs1.next()) {

                    return true;

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }


    }



    <%@page import="com.vechile.dao.UserDAO"%>
    <%@page import="com.vechile.model.DriverSearchResult"%>
    <%@page import="com.vechile.model.Vehicle"%>
    <%@page import="com.vechile.model.Searching"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="com.vechile.dao.SearchDAO"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Booking Search Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%
    DriverSearchResult dSR = new DriverSearchResult();

    %>
    <table>
    <th>ID</th>
    <tr>
    <td><%=dSR.getId() %></td>
    </tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <tr>
    <td><%=dSR.getName() %></td>
    </tr>

    </table>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what is DriverSearchResult  ? Cant see it anywhere

Comment: What's null?  Doesn't the stack trace tell you the file and line number at which the exception was thrown?  Don't you have access to a debugger?

Comment: @duffymo - I am pursuing my mca and this is my internship project. My HOD told me to use servlet only. What should I do ? I know about modern development methods.

Comment: It is printing `0` and `null` on the webpage. He creates a new object which is uninitialized.

Comment: I'd say Adam Arold has it right.  A debugger will let you fix this faster than asking here.  Learning how to debug is an important skill.

Comment: @duffymo - there is no exception thrown its just showing null. I debug the code but didnt find any error.

Comment: There is an exception thrown; you've got to be catching it in an empty catch block and not echoing the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you create a `new` `DriverSearchResult` in your jsp code:

```
DriverSearchResult dSR = new DriverSearchResult();
```

Since it is a new object its values are uninitialized. Then you print them out.

The problematic code:

```
 <%
    DriverSearchResult dSR = new DriverSearchResult(); // <- you create a new object

    %>
    <table>
    <th>ID</th>
    <tr>
    <td><%=dSR.getId() %></td> <!-- <-- you print its id which is 0 -->
    </tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <tr>
    <td><%=dSR.getName() %></td> <!-- <-- you print its name which is null -->
    </tr>
```